# Adding two periods on nodatime

Tags: c#, asp.net, nodatime

Where listObjAge is a list with multiple periods;

```
Period objTotalPeriod = listObjAge[0].period;
for (int i = 1; i < listObjAge.Count; i++) {
   objTotalPeriod += listObjAge[i].period;
}
```

In-short:
**What i am getting:**

```
listObjAge[0].period + listObjAge[1].period = ????.
2 yr 1 mnth 28 days  + 0 yr 8 mnth 30 days  = 2 yr 9 mnth 58 days 
// this result is not wrong but is there any way to correctly add days for the above code.
```

**What i am expecting:**

```
2 yr 1 mnth 28 days  + 0 yr 8 mnth 30 days  = 2 yr 10 mnth 28 days
```

As you can see i want to add results of two period. Is there any way we can achieve it using nodatime.

**Solved:**

I know its not correct theoretically. But it worked for me.

```
int intDays = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listObjAge.Count; i++) {
     intDays += listObjAge[i].period.Days; // adding all the days for every period
}

strYear = (intDays / 365).ToString();
strMonth = ((intDays % 365) / 30).ToString();
strDays = ((intDays % 365) % 30).ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you think 58 days == 1 month and 28 days? A month (in the Gregorian calendar) can be anything from 28 to 31 days.

Comment: According to requirement client need want to consider a month a 30 days :-}

Comment: @PratikGhag: How were we meant to guess that from the question? And why are you dividing by 31 in your code, given that? Does your client understand that if they add 360 days they'll end up adding a year, "losing" 5 days? I think you should explain to the client that calendar arithmetic is a bit more complicated than that, and try to get to the bottom of what they really want to achieve.

Comment: Hello @JonSkeet, sorry my bad, it's 30 not 31. My question is out of the scope of original question. I just wanted to count total time in years months and days format for multiple duration (like work exp of a person having worked in multiple location). In short what I did was I calculated total no of days for each duration and then adding the days from each duration to get grand total days, then i applied above given solution to get my result.

Comment: @Pratik: Well you can certainly write your own normalisation code. You could make it an extension method - you just need to be aware that you will end up with odd results, such as 372 days being one year...

Comment: Dear @JonSkeet, let me give you an example and guide me if this is correct or not.Example start: Consider a user having 2 work exp, 1st from:1st Jan 2014 to: 3rd march 2016 which gives "2 years 2 months 2 days" or 792 days, 2nd from:10th March 2016 to: 3rd Feb 2017 which gives "0 years 10 months 24 days" or 330 days. Now using given solution i get his total worked experience as "3 years 0 months and 27 days", which is absolutely correct, if you add the experience of his previous 2 jobs.
I hope i made myself clear.

Comment: If a month is 31 days, why is 10 months and 24 days 330 days rather than 334 days? (This is the problem - using different units will give different results...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something to normalize the months and days (and weeks?). The existing `Normalize` method deals with everything from "days downwards" (e.g. hours) so you can use that to start with:

```
public static Period NormalizeIncludingMonths(this Period period, int daysPerMonth)
{
    period = period.Normalize();
    int extraMonths = days / daysPerMonth;
    int months = period.Months + extraMonths;
    int extraYears = months / 12;
    // Simplest way of changing just a few parts...
    var builder = period.ToBuilder();
    builder.Years += extraYears;
    builder.Months = months % 12;
    builder.Days = days % daysPerMonth;
    return builder.Build();
}
```

So in your case, it sounds like you might want:

```
objTotalPeriod = objTotalPeriod.NormalizeIncludingMonths(31);
```

Note that arithmetic using this may well produce "odd" results, just as part of the nature of calendrical arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks again @jon skeet.

Comment: Can you explain in short what exactly it does 'objPeriod = objPeriod.Normalize();'

Comment: @PratikGhag: Well it calls the `Normalize` method, which will do normalization for all the fixed-length parts - so it converts "25 hours" into "1 day at 1 hour" for example.

Comment: But it won't convert 14 months to 1 year 2 months?. Will it work just on time?

Comment: @PratikGhag: It doesn't do anything with years/months, no. (Partly because there are calendar systems which don't always have 12 months in a year.) It *does* convert weeks into days. Basically, read the documentation :)

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the user guide for Noda Time that describes arithmetic http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/arithmetic - look under the section "Adding a Period" for more information.

---

It's easiest to think about where this can be confusing with an example. Suppose we add "one month minus three days" to January 30th 2011:

```
Period period = Period.FromMonths(1) - Period.FromDays(3);
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2011, 1, 30);
date = date + period;
```

If you give this puzzle to a real person, they may well come up with an answer of "February 27th" by waiting until the last moment to check the validity. Noda Time will give an answer of February 25th, as the above code is effectively evaluated as:

```
Period period = Period.FromMonths(1) - Period.FromDays(3);
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2011, 1, 30);
date = date + Period.FromMonths(1); // February 28th (truncated)
date = date - Period.FromDays(3); // February 25th
```

> The benefit of this approach is simplicity and predictability: when you know the rules, it's very easy to work out what Noda Time will do. **The downside is that if you don't know the rules, it looks like it's broken.**

---

### With your code

According to the documentation, the result you are getting is the **expected behavior** based on the "rules". Simply, your addition operation on two two periods will evaluate to:

```
Years (2 + 0) = 2
Months(1 + 8) = 9
Days (28 + 30) = 58
```

> Your comment:
>   `this result is not wrong but is there any way to correctly add days for the above code.`

**What do you mean as "correct"? Are you saying that 28 + 30 = 58 is incorrect?**

---

### Alternatives

```
int days = 28 + 30; // carry over your days and +1 month or whatever logic you had in mind
int months = 1 + 8;
Period p1 = new PeriodBuilder { Days = days, Months = months }.Build();
```

Comment: The user is asking explicitly how to do it with NodaTime.

Comment: I don't want to add two dates. I want to add two periods objects.

Comment: Dude, i dont want to add days or years or  months to a specific date. I just want to add two periods objects like Period + Period.

Comment: @PratikGhag - I'm trying to tell you that the result you are getting by adding the two periods will evaluate to the Years, Months, Days as noted by the documentation. Maybe I am not understanding your question... I'm adding the two periods as you stated in your question.

Comment: LOL. There can be only 30 days in a month so i wanted it to round off the days to month. Really appreatiate your efforts dude.

Comment: @PratikGhag - but you keep telling me you want to add `Periods` -- when I suggested you use a date type you say "No"... I'm totally lost. `Periods` types work as noted in the documentation.

Comment: @PratikGhag `There can be only 30 days in a month`: that's totally and absolutely false

Comment: I know @Jcl but for this requirement I need to consider a month of 30 days.

Comment: @PratikGhag but you are asking for a library to solve your specific needs which are just not true... that's like saying: "I need to have days of 27 hours but nodatime doesn't act like I want it to!". You'll have to make your calculations yourself if you have specific needs

Comment: what i wanted was to add 2 or more results from two period(nodatime object) to get a third period.

Comment: @PratikGhag A regular month is not a fixed number of days, so NodaTime (as a generic time library) cannot split 58 days into 1 month and 28 days. *Your* specific application has specific needs, so you will need to code those specific rules yourself.

Comment: @PratikGhag - use my alternative solution at the bottom and just make a condition, when `days >= 30` then `months++`

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts @Svek. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
public static Period add(Period b, Period c)
{

   int years = b.year + c.year;
   int months = b.month + c.month;
   int days= b.days + c.days;
   return new PeriodBuilder { Days = days, Months = months , Years  = years}.Build();
}
```

Comment: You can't use Period objPeriod = new Period(),it will throw exception. There is not constructer for period or something like that.

Comment: That won't compile outside the `Period` class - you can't create operators which work on entirely different classes. Besides, the `Period` class *already* has a `+` operator which does this - you haven't addressed the normalization aspect.